# While condition in my sql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a sp to run recursively based on while condition . But while condition is not working as expected.

```
BEGIN
declare moduleid VARCHAR(3);
declare parent VARCHAR(3);
declare flag int DEFAULT 0;

SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 3;
set moduleid = mdlid;
set parent   = '';
set flag     = 0;

select moduleid;

set parent = (
    select
        ms.parentModule as parentModule
    from
        x ms
    where
        ms.moduleid = moduleid
);

select parent;

set flag = if( 'MNU' = parent, 0, 1 );

select flag;

while (flag <> 0) DO

    select
        ms.menuname
    from
        x ms
    where
        ms.moduleId = parent;

    select 'called recursive';

    call usp_testwhile(parent);

end WHILE;

END
```

though the flag value is 0 the statement inside while is executing.

The original intention of this sp is to stop when the parentmenu is MNU.
For eg the table structure of x is as follows,

```
moduleid    parentmodule  menuname
aaa         bbb           alpha1
bbb         ccc           alpha2
ccc         MNU           alpha3
```

Expected functionality is 
call spname('aaa');

Now module id is aaa and parent is bbb. In while i'm checking parent !='MNU' condition fails and cycle 2 begins

Now module id is bbb and parent is ccc. In while i'm checking parent !='MNU' condition fails and cycle 3 begins

Now module id is ccc and parent is MNU. In while i'm checking parent !='MNU' condition satisfy and should stop executing .

Comment: Your `flag` variable is not static or global - it's local to the sproc's scope - if you call the sproc from itself then a new instance of `flag` (and `moduleid`, `parent` and `max_sp_recursion_depth`) will be created. You need to pass a depth indicator as a parameter instead.

Comment: @Dai, it's surely the right answer, so why not post it as one?

Answer (score 0):

The flag variable that you defined is not passed to the recursive calls, it only exists within the scope of the each procedure call

I would suggest updating this the call to:
   call usp_testwhile(parent);
To actually include the flag in some way.

Or alternatively, just drop the flag variable and do your Parent = 'MNU' check directly in the while loop.

The same goes for all variables you defined in here, if you aren't passing them to the recursive call they are effectively going to be reset on every recursive call.

Comment: As suggested , flag variable is dropped and parent equals is checked in while loop directly.   Still problem exist                                                                                           
 BEGIN
declare parent VARCHAR(3);
SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 3;
select mdlid;
set parent = (
    select ms.parentModule as parentModule from
        modulestructure ms
    where
        ms.moduleid = mdlid
);
select parent;
while (parent <> 'MNU') DO
select ms.menuname from modulestructure ms
    where ms.moduleId = parent;
call usp_testwhile(parent);
end WHILE;
END

Comment: Updated answer above based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the above problem is achieved with if condition.
In the above code while loop doesn't work as expected.

```
if (parent != 'MNU') then
set @menuname=(select 
    ms.menuname
from
    x ms
where
    ms.moduleId = parent);
#select @menuname;
set @conMenu = CONCAT(@menuname,COALESCE(menuname, ''));

select @conMenu;
call usp_testwhile(parent,@conMenu);
end if;
```